# Is Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC open source?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to reproduce an issue with an incompatibility between Kendo UI's DataSourceResponse class and ServiceStack.Text Json Serializer.  I can only locate the source code for the client side Javascript.

Does anyone know if Kendo UI's C# source code for ASP.NET MVC is available?

I supposed I could reflect it, but I wouldn't be able to share any of the code in an issue report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered under the Kendo license agreement: https://www.kendoui.com/purchase/license-agreement/kendo-ui-complete-mvc.aspx

> 1.3 Source Code. The Software’s source code is provided to You so that you can create modifications under the terms of this Agreement.
>   1.3.3 You acknowledge that the Software’s source code is confidential and contains valuable and proprietary trade secrets of Telerik. Except as provided for in Section 2.2 of this Agreement, **under no circumstances may any portion of the Software’s source code or any modified version of the source code be distributed, disclosed or otherwise made available to any third party**.

However, if you're filing a ticket with Telerik directly then they're a first-party, so you should share anything and everything you discover with them.